# R Regex remove everything after Underscore if underscore is after position 3

Tags: r, regex

I have been searching for a solution for two days.

Here is a sample of what my data looks like and what I would like to achieve:

```
dat <- c("f__dfty","fd_fgtekg","f_glgkt_s2","f_glgkt_s3","fthssfy_s2","fthssfy_s3","h__gkdnt_s2","sedfgrtsd")
dat <- c("f__dfty","fd_fgtekg","f_glgkt","f_glgkt","fthssfy","fthssfy","h__gkdnt","sedfgrtsd")
```

I need to remove everything after an "_", but not if the underscore is in position 2 and or 3 of the string.  Not every string will have an underscore.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but maybe you can use substring() to only retain the characters after the third character

Comment: `^(.{3}[^_]*).*$`? See it in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/DnNyaZ/2) (with modification for use with multi-line input). If you might have strings less than 3 characters use the code [here](https://regex101.com/r/DnNyaZ/3) instead `^((?:.{3})?[^_]*).*$`

Comment: `sub("^(....*)_.*$", "\\1", dat)` seems to work on the example.

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer, with edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brief

Not sure about length of strings, so I'll assume any length can be used.

---

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/DnNyaZ/3/)

**Regex**

```
^((?:.{3})?[^_\s]+).*$
```

Note: You can actually use `^((?:.{3})?[^_]+).*$` instead, but since my example on regex101 uses multiline input to simplify things, I posted the code I used there.

**Substitution**

```
$1
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
f__dfty
fd_fgtekg
f_glgkt_s2
f_glgkt_s3
fthssfy_s2
fthssfy_s3
h__gkdnt_s2
sedfgrtsd
aaaaaaa_aaaa
```

#### Output

```
f__dfty
fd_fgtekg
f_glgkt
f_glgkt
fthssfy
fthssfy
h__gkdnt
sedfgrtsd
aaaaaaa
```

---

### Explanation

- Assert position at beginning of line `^`
- Capture the following

  - Optional match of any character 3 times `(?:.{3})?`
  - Match between 1 and unlimited of any character not present in the set `_\s` (`\s` to prevent newline matches in example on regex101; this can be removed from your code if looping through an array/list/etc.) `[^_\s]+`
- Match any character any number of times `.*`
- Assert position at the end of the line `$`
- Replace with first capture group `$1`

Comment: So I cannot seem to get this to work as expected in R.  Here is my code: dat$Pattern<-gsub("^(.{3}[^_\\s]*).*$", "", dat$Pattern)  What do I put in the replace portion?

Comment: @ChuckDickens I believe replacements in R use `\\1` instead of `$1`